# Author affiliations and date formatting

Tags: titles, amsart, affiliation

I am using `amsart`. But I do not want the author affiliations to be in small-caps which seems to be the default style in `amsart`. Instead I want them to be *italics* and **8pt**. Also I want the date to be printed at the end of the document, after the references. Help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The `amsart` document class is meant to be used for papers that will be published in one of the AMS's journals (and similar outlets). Do you have a different journal group in mind for your paper, or papers? If so, do the alternative journals provide their own LaTeX document classes and/or formatting packages?

Comment: yes. i have to submit to a different journal and unfortunately they do not provide any class. But amsart is the only way i know where i can get author affiliations at the end of the document which is one of the formatting requirements of the journal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method to achieve this. We need to do the following:

1. Empty the macros `\@setdate` which prints the date in the title page.
2. Add a newly created macro (viz `\@Setdate`) to `\enddoc@text` which prints the affiliation at the end of the document.
3. Set the font style of affiliation to *italic* and font size to 8pt in the `\@setaddresses` macro which puts affiliation, current address and email at the end of the document using `\enddoc@text` hook.

These hacks are now added between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the sample `amsart` template given below:

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Beginning of amsart.template
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%     AMS-LaTeX v.2 template for use with amsart
%
%     Remove any commented or uncommented macros you do not use.

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\let\@setdate\@empty
\def\date#1{\gdef\@Date{#1}}\let\@Date\@empty
\def\@Setdate{\datename\ \@Date\@addpunct.}
\def\enddoc@text{\ifx\@empty\@Setdate \else\par\addvspace\bigskipamount\indent%
  {\footnotesize\@Setdate}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\@translators \else\@settranslators\fi
  \ifx\@empty\addresses \else\@setaddresses\fi}
\def\@setaddresses{\par
  \nobreak \begingroup
\footnotesize
  \def\author##1{\nobreak\addvspace\bigskipamount}%
  \def\\{\unskip, \ignorespaces}%
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \def\address##1##2{\begingroup
    \par\addvspace\bigskipamount\indent
    \@ifnotempty{##1}{(\ignorespaces##1\unskip) }%
    {\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\itshape\ignorespaces##2}\par\endgroup}%
  \def\curraddr##1##2{\begingroup
    \@ifnotempty{##2}{\nobreak\indent\curraddrname
      \@ifnotempty{##1}{, \ignorespaces##1\unskip}\/:\space
      ##2\par}\endgroup}%
  \def\email##1##2{\begingroup
    \@ifnotempty{##2}{\nobreak\indent\emailaddrname
      \@ifnotempty{##1}{, \ignorespaces##1\unskip}\/:\space
      \ttfamily##2\par}\endgroup}%
  \def\urladdr##1##2{\begingroup
    \def~{\char`\~}%
    \@ifnotempty{##2}{\nobreak\indent\urladdrname
      \@ifnotempty{##1}{, \ignorespaces##1\unskip}\/:\space
      \ttfamily##2\par}\endgroup}%
  \addresses
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Sample title}

%    Remove any unused author tags.

%    author one information
\author{First Name}
\address{Sample, Affiliation}
\curraddr{Current, Address}
\email{someone@somewhere.com}
\thanks{Sample template downloaded from ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/amslatex/classes/amsart.template.}

%    author two information
\author{Second Author}
\address{Second, Affiliation}
\curraddr{Address, Second}
\email{anybody@somewhere.com}
\thanks{This is the second author}

\subjclass[2000]{Primary 0000, 1111}
%    For articles to be published after 1 January 2010, you may use
%    the following version:
%\subjclass[2010]{Primary }

\keywords{template, amsart}

\date{24 July 2013}

\dedicatory{Blah blah blah.}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[4]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} First reference.

\bibitem{2} Second reference.

\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% End of amsart.template
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope this helps.